# How to connect to SAP from VBA in 7.50+ when a message server and port are required

Tags: saprfc

When connecting silently from VBA to SAP I am running into a problem when a message server and port are required.

In SAPGUI 7.50 forward, SAP made a change. These silent connections always worked prior to 7.50.  Apparently you have to fill in the connection's .GroupName and .MessageServer properties. However, there is no property to attach the port to. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Fill the variable .System with the three-letter system ID of the backend. Like SAPGui, the VB application should then automatically find the message server port from the C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\services file.

For example, if the backend's Sys-ID is "ABC", then the services file will contain a line like

```
sapmsABC      3600/tcp
```

Comment: Hi, great answer! Where can we find the backend's Sys-ID?

Comment: It's listed in SAPLogon in the column "SID".
Or, if you don't have SAPGui installed, but have access to the installation directory of the SAP system: it is usually installed in a directory named /usr/sap/SID